# Como um colormap de uma superfície pode ser mapeado a uma função escalar?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, 3d

Tradução da [pergunta que fiz no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720848/how-can-a-3d-surface-colormap-be-mapped-to-a-scalar-function):

Eu tenho uma função escalar que representa o potencial elétrico numa superfície esférica. Quero plotar , para um dado raio, a superfície e mapear seus pontos a cores baseado na função potencial.

Como posso mapear tal função à superfície? Suspeito que tenha haver com os argumentos passados à função [ax.plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface). Tentei usar o argumento: `facecolors=potencial(x,y,z)`, ma recebi `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument.` Olhando no [código fonte do terceiro exemplo](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo3.py), há:

```
# Create an empty array of strings with the same shape as the meshgrid, and
# populate it with two colors in a checkerboard pattern.
colortuple = ('y', 'b')
colors = np.empty(X.shape, dtype=str)
for y in range(ylen):
    for x in range(xlen):
        colors[x, y] = colortuple[(x + y) % len(colortuple)]
```

Que eu não entendi, nem tenho ideia de como *linkar* com uma função escalar.

**Meu código**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from scipy import special    

def potencial(x,y,z, a=1., v=1.):
    r = np.sqrt( np.square(x) + np.square(y) + np.square(z) )    
    p = r/z #cos(theta)
    asr = a/r
    s=0
    s += np.polyval(special.legendre(1), x) * 3/2*np.power(asr, 2)
    s += np.polyval(special.legendre(3), x) * -7/8*np.power(asr, 4)
    s += np.polyval(special.legendre(5), x) * 11/16*np.power(asr, 6)    
    return v*s

# criar dados
def sphere_surface(r):
    u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
    x = r * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
    y = r * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
    z = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
    return x,y,z

x,y,z = sphere_surface(1.5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Plotar a superficie
surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
# Está mapeado aos valores do eixo-z

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Resposta traduzida ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43721522/6152534)):

Em princípio há duas maneiras de colorir um *plot* de superfície no matplotlib.

1. Usar o argumento `cmap` para especificar um *colormap*. Neste caso a cor será escolhida de acordo com o *array* `z`. Neste caso isto não é desejado,
2. Usar o argumento `facecolors`. Ele espera um *array* de cores da mesma forma (*shape*) que z.

Portanto, neste caso precisamos escolher a opção 2 e construir um *array* de cores. Para este fim, pode-se escolher um *colormap*. Um *colormap* mapeia valores entre 0 e 1 a uma cor. Como o potencial tem valores muito acima e abaixo deste intervalo, é preciso normalizá-lo para o intervalo [0,1].
Matplotlib já providencia uma função de ajuda para fazer esta normalização e como o potencial tem uma dependência 1/x, uma escala de cores logarítmica pode ser adequada.

No final as *facecolors* podem ser dadas por um array

```
colors = cmap(norm(potential(...)))
```

A parte que falta agora é a barra de cores (*colorbar*). Para que ela seja *linkada* às cores do *plot* de superfície, precisamos, manualmente, montar um *ScalarMappable* com o *colormap* e a instância de normalização, o qual podemos então fornecer ao *colorbar*.

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, norm=norm)
sm.set_array(pot)
fig.colorbar(sm, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

Aqui está um exemplo completo

```
from __future__ import division
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np
from scipy import special    

def potencial(x,y,z, a=1., v=1.):
    r = np.sqrt( np.square(x) + np.square(y) + np.square(z) )    
    p = z/r #cos(theta)
    asr = a/r
    s=0
    s += np.polyval(special.legendre(1), p) * 3/2*np.power(asr, 2)
    s += np.polyval(special.legendre(3), p) * -7/8*np.power(asr, 4)
    s += np.polyval(special.legendre(5), p) * 11/16*np.power(asr, 6)    
    return v*s

# Make data
def sphere_surface(r):
    u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
    x = r * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
    y = r * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
    z = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
    return x,y,z

x,y,z = sphere_surface(1.5)
pot = potencial(x,y,z)


norm=matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm(1,vmin=pot.min(),vmax=pot.max())
colors=plt.cm.coolwarm(norm(pot))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Plot the surface
surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, facecolors=colors,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
# Set up colorbar
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, norm=norm)
sm.set_array(pot)
fig.colorbar(sm, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)


ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
plt.show()
```